# Why does Enctype="Multipart/formdata" doesn't works here

Tags: php, html, forms, enctype

This is my code which doesn't works when `Enctype="multipart/form-data"` is Included
This is the Code which doesn't works

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file'])&&isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "test";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

But when i remove `Enctype="multipart/form-data"` it works fine, but as i know the form with file handling requires the Enctype. what should i do ?

Comment: Since `$_POST['submit']` will never be set with that code, I don't see how removing the enctype could cause it work "work fine".

Comment: `$_POST['file']` < and you're dealing with "FILES" here and not "POST".

Answer (score 2):

when you are using only file uploads with Enctype="multipart/form-data" Use the below code to check the file data.

```
if(isset($_FILES)&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File information is stored in the $_FILES super global and not $_POST

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_FILES["file"]` for read your sumitted file.

[here a complete example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)